# How to crop orthophoto using GDAL

Tags: gdal, gps, gdalwarp, clip

I have orthophoto(GeoTiff) and 4 GPS coordinates that represent rectangle.

How can I crop orthophoto by using GDAL? (I need to remove areas outside of rectangle)

**UPDATE:**

I tried gdal_translate

`gdal_translate -projwin top_left_corner.longitute top_left_corner.latitude bottom_right_corner.longitute bottom_right_corner.latitude orthophoto.tif crop.tif`

But seems it expects top left corner and bottom right corner in other coordinate system?

Comment: @user30184 see update.

Comment: Which coordinate system are you working in?

Comment: -projwin is documented in http://www.gdal.org/gdal_translate.html. Default coordinate system is the same that is used for the output but there is also -projwin_srs parameter that can be used with GDAL version 2.0 and higher.

Comment: @MikkelLydholmRasmussen `gdalinfo` says that original tiff is Coordinate System is:
GEOGCS["WGS 84",
    DATUM["WGS_1984",
        SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],
    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],
    UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]]

Comment: It should work as is, under the assumption that your coordinates are correctly formatted.

Comment: @MikkelLydholmRasmussen I'm still confused, can you give example orthophotoplan crop using GPS coordinates of polygon by using GDAL?

Comment: gdal_translate -projwin 12.495601 55.719778 12.578243 55.682839 orthophoto.tif subset.tif